# Magento How to compression already uploaded product images

Tags: magento

I want to know how to compress already existing product images which are there in my magento stores so it will help to load my site faster.

is there any techniques which will help me to load site faster which contents heavy images

each images contents size of more then 1 MB

will any one have any idea about this?

I just want to increase my site performance, I try to re-size it will outputting them but it will reduce the quality of images, and also it's not affected my site performance.

Waiting your kind response!!!

Comment: Doesn't Magento scale the images before outputting them?

Comment: but my site contents lots of images, i try to reduce it while outputting them but then also it will slow down my site performance and quality

Comment: Does Magento not already scale your images before outputting them?

Comment: yes it is but it will reduce my pic quality and my main area of interest to increase quality of images with site performance increas

Answer (score 0):

Try processing them with [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/):

```
find /path/to/media/catalog -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 mogrify -strip -interlace Plane -quality 85% -monitor
```

This will strip metadata, enable progressive loading and lower the jpg quality to 85%.
Be sure to make a backup first!